# Handle pagination in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy python to scrape a particular site. The site has pagination of the form below:

http://www.example.com/s/ref=lp_1805560031_pg_4?rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A%21976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cn%3A1805560031&**page=4**&ie=UTF8&qid=1400668237

How can i include handle the pagination in this case if i want to scrape from say page 1 to page 30;

I tried this :

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/s/ref=lp_1805560031_pg_4?rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A%21976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cn%3A1805560031&page=%s&ie=UTF8&qid=1400668237' % page for page in xrange(1,30)]
```

But its not working

**EDIT :**  Am using domain as example.com just for the question purpose

Comment: Did you try to open other urls in `start_urls` manually?

Comment: @WKPlus yup manually they are opening ... am getting the following error :   `  start_urls = ['http://www.exampl.co/s/ref=lp_1805560031_pg_4?rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A%21976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cn%3A1805560031&page=%s&ie=UTF8&qid=1400668237' % page for page in xrange(1,30)] `
ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/s/ref=lp_1805560031_pg_4?rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A%21976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cn%3A1389432031%2Cn%3A1805560031&page={0}&ie=UTF8&qid=1400668237'.format(page) for page in xrange(1,30)]
```